# Render not work like in the 3d viewport

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, rigging

So everything is working fine in viewport, the wheel attach with the car rigging in the viewport. But when i render animation by png single frame. The wheel come off the car start moving on it own but no its not like that in viewport. Can someone help me to fix this?
Thanks
P/s: sorry for my bad english
the link to the my file here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bLhawJBKrTjv6DNR-uWVc7UMC3eDHZVO?usp=drive_link

[image]
[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: oh ok but i cant up load it to blend exchange cuz my blend file is 111mb so i upload it on my drive link here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bLhawJBKrTjv6DNR-uWVc7UMC3eDHZVO?usp=drive_link